# matplotlib different colors in 2 different pc

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, color-scheme

today I developed a simple class in python in order to get a plot style suitable for my purpose ... 
here the class :
this is the base class in which I define the colors ... in function colors , my particular interest is for the colors cycle named 'soft'

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter 
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
import matplotlib.pylab as pylab
import matplotlib
from cycler import cycler


class PlotBase(metaclass=ABCMeta):

   def __init__(self, title , filename : str = ' '):
      self.title = title
      self.filename = filename   

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   def findLimits(self):
         '''
             found the vectors limits in order to set the figure limits x,y
         '''
         _minX = 10E20
         _minY = 10E20
         _maxX = 0.000
         _maxY = 0.000
         for i in range(0,len(self.variable)-1,3):
            if _minX >= min(self.variable[i]):  
               _minX = min(self.variable[i])
            if _maxX <= max(self.variable[i]):
               _maxX = max(self.variable[i])
            if _minY >= min(self.variable[i+1]):  
               _minY = min(self.variable[i+1])
            if _maxY <= max(self.variable[i+1]):
               _maxY = max(self.variable[i+1])
         return [round(_minX,2), round(_maxX,2) , round(_minY,2) , round(_maxY,2)]

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   def save(self, filename : 'str -> name of the file with extension'):
       plt.savefig(filename)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   def colors(self, style : 'str (name of the pallette of line colors)'):
      if style == 'vega':
         style = "cycler('color', ['1F77B4', 'FF7F0E', '2CA02C', 'D62728', '9467BD', '8C564B', 'E377C2', '7F7F7F', 'BCBD22', '17BECF'] )" 
      elif style == 'gg': 
         style = "cycler('color', ['E24A33', '348ABD', '988ED5', '777777', 'FBC15E', '8EBA42', 'FFB5B8'])"
      elif style == 'brewer':           
         style = "cycler('color', ['66C2A5', 'FC8D62', '8DA0CB', 'E78AC3', 'A6D854', 'FFD92F', 'E5C494', 'B3B3B3'] )"
      elif style == 'soft1':   
         style = "cycler('color', ['8DA0CB', 'E78AC3', 'A6D854', 'FFD92F', 'E5C494', 'B3B3B3', '66C2A5', 'FC8D62'] )"
      elif style == 'tthmod':      
         style = "cycler('color', ['30a2da', 'fc4f30', 'e5ae38', '6d904f', '8b8b8b'])"
      elif style == 'grayscale':
         style = "cycler('color', ['252525', '525252', '737373', '969696', 'BDBDBD', 'D9D9D9', 'F0F0F0', 'F0F0FF' ])"
      elif style == 'grayscale2':
         style = "cycler('color', ['525252', '969696', 'BDBDBD' ,'D9D9D9', 'F0F0F0', 'F0F0FF' ])"
      return style  

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   def linestyle(self , linestyle : str):
      if linestyle == 'linetype1':
         linestyle = "cycler('linestyle', ['-', '--', ':', '-.'])"
      if linestyle == 'linetype2':
         linestyle = "cycler('linestyle', ['-', ':', '-.', '--'])"
      return linestyle
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   @abstractmethod
   def plot(self,*args,**kwargs):
      """
         Abstract method!
         the derived class must implement its self method 
      """
      pass
```

then I define the usable callable class :

```
class TimesPlot(PlotBase):
   '''   
         mathpazo style (LaTeX-class) plot suitable for:
           - palatino fonts template / beamer 
           - classic thesis style 
           - mathpazo package 
   '''
   def __init__(self,title,filename: str= ' '):
         super().__init__(title,filename)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   def plot(self, *args,**kwargs):   #   

         self.variable = [*args]
         if len(self.variable) % 3 != 0:
            print('Error variable must be coupled (even number)')
            raise AttributeError('you must give 2 array x,y followed by string label for each plot')
         '''  
               plot method, define all the parameter for the plot
               the rendering of the figure is setting to beh "light" 

               -->   TODO : define parameter in order to set the size of figure/font/linewidth
         '''

         #plt.rc('text', usetex=True )
         #plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{times}"]
         #plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble']=[r"\usepackage{mathpazo}"]

         plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'   #'serif'
         #plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ''#'DejaVu Sans' #'Tahoma' #, , 'Lucida Grande', 'Verdana']
         plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 14
         #plt.rcParams['font.name'] = 'Helvetica'
         plt.rcParams['font.style'] = 'italic'
         #plt.rc('font',family='' ,size=16, weight='normal')



         plt.rc_context({'axes.edgecolor':'#999999' })   # BOX colors
         plt.rc_context({'axes.linewidth':'1' })   # BOX width
         plt.rc_context({'axes.xmargin':'0' })     
         plt.rc_context({'axes.ymargin':'0' })     
         plt.rc_context({'axes.labelcolor':'#555555' })     
         plt.rc_context({'axes.edgecolor':'999999' })     
         plt.rc_context({'axes.axisbelow':'True' })     
         plt.rc_context({'xtick.color':'#555555' })   # doesn't affect the text
         plt.rc_context({'ytick.color':'#555555' })   # doesn't affect the text
         plt.rc_context({ 'axes.prop_cycle': self.colors('soft1')}) 

         #plt.rc('lines', linewidth=3)

         fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(10,6))



         plt.title(self.title,color='#555555',fontsize=18)
         plt.xlabel('time [s]',fontsize=16)
         plt.ylabel('y(t)',fontsize=16)
         #plt.grid(linestyle='dotted')
         plt.grid(linestyle='--')
         #plt.figure(1)
                  #ax.edgecolor('gray')
         for i in range(0,len(self.variable)-1,3):
            plt.plot(self.variable[i],self.variable[i+1], linewidth=3, label= self.variable[i+2])   

         ax.set_xlim( self.findLimits()[0] , self.findLimits()[1] )
         ax.set_ylim( self.findLimits()[2] , self.findLimits()[3] + 0.02 )

         majorLocator    = MultipleLocator(20)
         majorFormatter  = FormatStrFormatter('%f')
         minorXLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.05)
         minorYLocator   = MultipleLocator(0.05)

         ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minorXLocator)
         ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minorYLocator)
         ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
         ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')

         #axes.xmargin: 0
         #axes.ymargin: 0

         #plt.legend(fontsize=10)
         #handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
         #ax.legend(handles, labels)
         #ax.legend(frameon=True, fontsize=12)

         #text.set_color('gray')
         #leg = plt.legend(framealpha = 0, loc = 'best')
         #ax.legend(borderpad=1)
         legend = leg = plt.legend(framealpha = 1, loc = 'best', fontsize=14,fancybox=False, borderpad =0.4)
         leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('#dddddd')
         leg.get_frame().set_linewidth(1.2)
         plt.setp(legend.get_texts(), color='#555555')

         plt.tight_layout(0.5)
         if self.filename != ' ': 
            super().save(self.filename)
         plt.show()
```

The falls happens because in my university pc this class give me a plot using the soft1 scheme of colors ... at home with same version of python It use the default set of colors (corresponding to the set that I defined named 'vega') ... not only the line colors change ... also the box of the plot have different colors contrast ... could somebody help me ??

I call this class simply passing them 6 vector (in order to obtain 3 curve) as follow :

```
  fig1 = makeplot.TimesPlot('Solution of Differential Equations','p1.pdf')
   fig1.plot(fet,feu,'Explicit Euler',bet,beu,'Implicit Euler',x,y,'Analytical')
```

May you please help me to understand the reason why this happens ? I've tried in my home from archlinux and gentoo .... while in my desktop pc in which the class works correctly I use the last debian

Comment: The example seems much too complicated to ask about different colorscemes (see [mcve]). Also, you can probably imagine that people will not be able to reproduce your problem with the above code, simply because they will get a single output from it and don't have access to your two different configurations from which to see any difference.